# How do I initialize a static random generator data member?

Tags: c++, class, initialization, static-members, most-vexing-parse

I have `Random` class, and I don`t know how correctly initialize its static data members.

```cpp
// random.h
#pragma once

#include <random>

class Random
{
private:
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<float> sDistribution_;
    static std::mt19937 sGenerator_;
};
```

```cpp
// random.cpp
#include "random.h"

std::mt19937 Random::sGenerator_(std::random_device()); // error here
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> Random::sDistribution_(0.0f, 1.0f);
```

When I compile this, I get an error:

> declaration is not compatible with `std::mt19937`.

How do I correctly initialize this member?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Why not make them regular properties and have the class itself as a singleton, or even better, thread local?

Comment: Look up documentation for [std::random_device](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device)  the example is there.

Comment: Change `std::random_device()` to `std::random_device{}()`. `random_device` is not a function. It's a class, so you'll need to create an instance first, _then_ call it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cpp
std::mt19937 Random::sGenerator_(std::random_device());
```

is an instance of [*the most vexing parse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).
You wanted to perform [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), but you're actually:

> declaring `Random::sGenerator_` as a function taking a pointer to a function taking no parameters, and returning [`std::random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device). The `Random::sGenerator_` function returns [`std::mt19937`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine).

This is what the compiler thinks, and it conflicts with the original definition of `Random::sGenerator_`, which declares it as a static data member of type [`std::mt19937`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine).

The solution is very simple: [`std::random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) is a type, not a function, so you need to initialize it before calling it, like:

```cpp
std::mt19937 Random::sGenerator_{std::random_device{}()};
// or
std::mt19937 Random::sGenerator_{std::random_device()()};
// or
std::mt19937 Random::sGenerator_(std::random_device{}());
```

In general, preferring [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) is considered good practice by some, because it avoids this parsing ambiguity. Just be aware that it works differently when a type has a constructor taking [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) (not a problem for any of the types we're using).

#### Since C++17

You can also initialize the static data member in the class, like:

```cpp
class Random
{
private:
    static inline std::uniform_real_distribution<float> sDistribution_{0, 1};
    static inline std::mt19937 sGenerator_{std::random_device{}()};
};
```

*Note: if all your class does is storing static data members, it should likely just be a `namespace`, not a `class`.*